# Optional binding doesn't unwrap dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have the following dictionary

```
var menuItems: [[String: String?]] = [
    ["name": "Home", "identifier": "homeController"],
    ["name": "Page 2", "identifier": "page2"],
    ["name": "Page 3", "identifier": "page3"]]
```

Now I'm looping through the dictionary using the next code

```
var names: [String] = [String]()
for item in menuItems
{
    if let name = item["name"]
    {
        names.append(name)
    }
}
```

`if let name = item["name"]` should unwrap and assign the name to the `name` constant. Assigning works but unwrapping doesn't happen.

`names.append(name)` throws the exception `Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?`

Why doesn't the `item["name"]` get unwrapped?

Comment: Does the subscript not already returning an optional value?! So you're returning something like `String??` and not `String?`.

Comment: @DevAndArtist I [see](http://i.imgur.com/4CyZFMm.png). Thank you!

Comment: This could be unwrapped with `if let value = item["name"], name = value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item["name"]` do gets unwrapped. It is unwrapped to `String?`. Remember that dictionaries always return an optional values (for cases where a value does not exist for the given key).

In your case the value **IS** another optional of type string.

If your dictionary was declared as `[String: String]` (no `?` for the value type) then you would not have to unwrap the value with `!`

Comment: Didn't know that `item["name"]` gets unwrapped, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The answer from giorashc is correct but I thought I would post this as it might help someone in understanding the reason for this.

A dictionary is defined with generic parameters `K` and `V`.

So for a given dictionary `dict : [K:V]`

The output of `dict[k]` is of type `V?`.

In this case `K = String` and `V = String?`

therefore the type of the subscript access result is `String??`. Which as has already been pointed out is unwrapped to `String?`